# HighCharts Rendering Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am facing a strange issue with HighCharts,

My Javascript is as below

```
$('#chart').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: 'Smaple Chart'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Jan-2014'
    },
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false
    },
    series: {
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'abcde',
        data: [
            ["data1", 42],
            ["data2", 79],
            ["data3", 95],
            ["data4", 7],
            ["data5", 576],
            ["data6", 94]
        ]
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: 'true',
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: 'true',
                color: '#000',
                connectorColor: '#000',
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

However, the chart does not render.

Here is the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W24xk/2/) that i have created. Not sure what is going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah i found it with a bit of searching

Add `[` around `series` like such

```
series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'abcde',
        data: [
            ["data1", 42],
            ["data2", 79],
            ["data3", 95],
            ["data4", 7],
            ["data5", 576],
            ["data6", 94]
        ]
    }],
```